# can we apply class to checkbox input instedad of container div in cakephp

Tags: forms, cakephp, checkbox, input, cakephp-2.0

Here the code for checkbox generation

```
//code
echo $this->Form->select('Model.field', $options, array(
                                'multiple' => 'checkbox','div'=>'col-md-9',
                                'class' => 'required'
                            ));


//output
<div class="required" aria-required="true">
    <input type="checkbox" id="FormData6783" value="83" name="data[Model][field][]">
<label for="FormData6783">Sr. Secondary</label>
</div>
<div class="required" aria-required="true">
    <input type="checkbox" id="FormData6783" value="83" name="data[Model][field][]">
<label for="FormData6783">Secondary</label>
</div>
```

it applies class to container div instead of input.. Is there any way to apply class to input ?

Comment: Read the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses

Comment: @burzum This is CakePHP 2.

Comment: @Holt this happens when people aren't smart enough to add their version. Now that you say it, I see the dot notation for the model. Well, he will have to overload the FormHelper then and override the markup building code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to extend the FormHelper with your own helper and then overload the select method to [change the code that generates the select](http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/source-class-FormHelper.html#2053). Check [the BoostCake plugin](https://github.com/slywalker/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake) to get an idea of one way o changing [FormHelpers](https://github.com/slywalker/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake/blob/master/View/Helper/BoostCakeFormHelper.php) output.

You can then alias the helper to replace it app wide:

```
public $helpers = ['Form' => ['className' => 'MyForm']];
```